# 4 layer buck converter layout

Tags: pcb-layers

What is the standard layout for a 4 layer PCB that everyone follows for a buck converter or similar? I was planning to go like this:

1. Signal
2. Vcc
3. GND
4. Signal

Since inductors and FETS are noisiest of all I was thinking of having them on the top layer. Second layer for Vcc, bottom layer with the gate signal, voltage feedback, current sense from and to the IC and other routes that are not possible on the top layer. Third would hold the GND plane with no routing. A reasonably large exposed layer on the first and fourth layer for the MOSFETs to dissipate heat. Would this be a bad idea?

Should I have the GND in the second layer to keep the path to GND the shortest? Frequency is 280 kHz with top mount devices. Can we use the second layer for routing other signals like the MOSFET gate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper placement of VCC and GND copper pours in 4-layer PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429565/what-is-the-proper-placement-of-vcc-and-gnd-copper-pours-in-4-layer-pcb)

Comment: Three signal layers and no Vcc?

Comment: Add Vcc to the second layer and edited the question as well.

Comment: There is no "standard layout [...] that everyone follows". There's also no hard and fast requirement for layers to be dedicated to specific uses.

Comment: Would it be ok to have copper pour connecting the top layer to the bottom layer for heat dissipation from MOSFETs ? Would it cause shorts between the internal layers or have an effect in another way to the internal layers ?

Answer (score 1):

An unbroken ground plane on layer 3 or layer 2 is good, but don't let it lull you into a false sense of security.

The most important thing with those 'noisy' components is to arrange them so that the loop area enclosed by the changing current paths is as small is possible. Paradoxically this means that the tracks to the inductor are not the most critical, as the current through them does not change abruptly. It's the varying route through the switching device and freewheel diode that are critical.

As the switching device goes to ground, resist the temptation to simply connect it to the ground plane in some random place, connect it so that the loop area from it to the ground connection of the output filter capacitor (the place where the alternate current ends up) is as small as possible.

Once you've take care of those radiating loops, just simple tidiness will allow you to make use of all those layers to route the rest of the design. There's little need to have a VCC plane, it's just a waste of space on most designs. Make sure the tracks that take the input and output current are wide enough. Flood-filling all the layers will maximise the thermal conductivity of the board. It's usually good practice to ground those fills, not least because the vias add additional Z axis thermal conductivity.